# How a probably NULL-valued attribute could still reference another attribute in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints

Imagine MySQL table describing a folders in filesystem:

```sql
folder_id INT,
parent_folder_id INT,
folder_name VARCHAR(64)
```

And I want to add a constraint 'parent_folder_id REFERENCES folder_id' to be sure that no dead links are there in the DB.

But in case folder is in the top-level there is no parent folder, so it should be NULL. As far as I understand, constraint won't let me insert tuple with parent_folder_id = NULL.

How to design it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE `folder` (
    `folder_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `parent_folder_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    `folder_name ` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_folder` PRIMARY KEY (`folder_id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `folder` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_folder_parent_folder` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_folder_id`) REFERENCES `folder` (`folder_id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

The foreign key constraint won't kick in when `parent_folder_id` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd better using two triggers (one on insert and one on update) checking that **parent_folder_id** exists in your table in **folder_id** column; if not raise an error or discard the insert/update operation.
For root folder assign **parent_folder_id = 0** and use a `CASE` statement in your trigger to make this valid.

**EDITED:** use this as pseudo-code

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_ins BEFORE INSERT ON table
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.parent_folder_id > 0) THEN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(folder_id) FROM table 
          WHERE folder_id = NEW.parent_folder_id) = 0 THEN
              raise_an_error_here
      END
    END
  END
```

Comment: And how do you insert the root folder ?

Comment: Still a problem ... I had to insert the root entry before placing the contraint, because the parent_folder_id cannot be known before writing.

Comment: you will still have a null in the insert for the root folder, and triggers or constraints will react.

Comment: @Louis: root is the very first record inserted and for this you pass _parent_folder_id = 0_; trigger (with a CASE as I said) understands this and let the insert be completed gracefully. When you insert other dirs you can relate parent folder with id given on _folder_id_ field.

Comment: Looks like the good solution if you detect the root as the FIRST inserted record and allow (with case) a zero in parent_folder_id.

Comment: @Louis: well, OP makes inserts, so he knows which the root is... I think... Anyway, do you think solution I provided could be right or not?

Comment: @Louis: again, not using constraints, it's not necessary root is inserted first. It's enough inserting it using _parent_folder_id = 0_ even at the end...

Comment: @bazzilic: what do you think?

Comment: root must be inserted first because all first-level folders will have to reference him (and have his folder_id as their parent_folder_id), or do I miss something ?

Comment: @Louis: it's been a really hard night for me, I was missing that :)

Comment: So the trigger you suggested must detect the first inserted record, and in that case only, he may accept a null in the parent_folder_id, and you get your solution. Update your answer ;-)

Comment: @Louis: sorry, I know my English is really poor and my sleeping hours are few, so it's hard for me to make understand what I mean. I tell OP not to use constraints but only triggers. Let's talk about insert trigger, it must have a CASE statement on _parent_folder_id_ field: if  it's ZERO then insertion has to be made (it's the root); if it's not (it's a leaf) it must check a record with folder_id = NEW.parent_folder_id exists: if it does not raise an error (example [here](http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/))

Comment: My english is poor, too. Edit your answer with a rough sample, this is for you.

Answer (score 0):

I should just add a record in the folder table, called "root", for which the parent_folder is himself. But I never tested it and do not know if the system will accept this.

Comment: Well, that's a good idea to add such a meta-folder, thanks ) but I thought there could be something more elegant :)

Comment: You can add the constraint after inserting the root folder (or disable constraints), so this should work.

Comment: If there is a more elegant solution, I will vote it up ! I stay tuned.

Comment: @pablochan : yes, it is something like that that I commented in the other answer.

Comment: But still, how to add a folder referencing itself? At the moment of constraint check there is no tuple to reference...

Comment: yes, that's why the root has to be inserted BEFORE adding the constraints. OR work without constraints, but with triggers, and write a trigger that, when the folder_name is "root", allows the insert with a null in parent_folder_id... Anyway, it looks like a "workaround" and forces the name of the root to a known value...